# Can't edit scheduler in 4.8.2

Tags: iccube

Version 4.8.1 allowed editing of existing scheduled tasks. For example, you could disable or enable a task to run as scheduled. In the latest 4.8.2 version, it seems the only way to edit a scheduled task is to export / import scheduler definitions. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately a regression (missing UI icons). You can follow this [issue](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-114) - this should be fixed in the upcoming 4.8.3 version. In the meantime your workaround is correct.